# java: OutOfMemoryError: insufficient memory while running JUnits in Idea

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I am trying to run JUnits from my IntelliJ Idea
When I try to run the Test.java file it gives me an error saying that

> java: OutOfMemoryError: insufficient memory

I have tried increasing the memory allocated to Idea to as large as 6GB but it still gives me the same error, what am I missing :/

Increasing the following in **idea64.vmoptions** didn't help. current vmoption settings in /opt/idea/bin are:

```
-Xms124m
-Xmx2g
-XX:MaxPermSize=2g
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=196m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

PS:- the project has ~83k files and overall size of project is 1.1 GB

Below Error is encountered:-

> Information:Using javac 1.6.0_35 to compile java sources
>   Information:java: The system is out of resources. Information:java:
>   Consult the following stack trace for details. Information:java:  at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position$LineMapImpl.build(Position.java:139)
>   Information:java:     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position.makeLineMap(Position.java:63)
>   Information:java:     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.getLineMap(Scanner.java:1105)
>   Information:java:     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:512)
>   Information:java:     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:550)
>   Information:java:     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:804)
>   Information:java:     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
>   Information:java:     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353) Information:java:
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:115)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:166)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:364)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:276)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:190)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:162)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:992)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:739)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:769)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:702)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:523)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:314)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:179)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:216)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:111)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:132)
>   Information:java:     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
>   Information:java:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>   Information:java:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   Information:java:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   Information:java:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   Information:java:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   Information:java:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'app'
>   Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 3 min
>   19 sec Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Error:java:
>   OutOfMemoryError: insufficient memory

[image: IDEA COMPILER SETTINGS]

Comment: You can use `-Xms1g` or `-Xmx4g` BTW 4G = 4096M

Comment: Think about this, if you called `System.exit(0);` or your test crashed the JVM, would you want your IDEA to die as well?

Comment: Could you provide more details for the OutOfMemoryError (is it heap? permgen?), when it happens (after some test run or at the beginning)?

Comment: @frant.hartm i have attached the error log above

Comment: Or try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66823924/1507602

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Idea runs unit tests in a separate java process.

You need to use

```
Run -> Edit Configurations...
```

and add your `-XmxNNNm` to VM Options.

For example:

```
-ea -Xmx1024m
```

The "-ea" means "enable assertions".

If your unit test(s) can't run in a 1GB of memory then it's possible that you have a memory leak.

Comment: currently the value in VM Options is -ea, what does it mean and what shall i change it to. please explain a bit more

Comment: even restarting IDEA after changing vmoptions to -Xmx4024m doesn't help. What do i do?

Answer (score 57):

Based on your log the problem is in compiler heap space.

Go to

```
Settings -> Compiler -> Build process heap size (MB)
```

and increase that value.

Comment: tried changing it from 700 to 2000, still didn't work :/

Comment: How much physical memory and swap your machine has?

Comment: 250GB HDD, 8GB RAM, 8.4GB of swap space of which 0.889GB is used up and Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q9400 @ 2.66GHz × 4

Comment: If you have 88% of your ram allocated it can't allocate additional 2G for the compiler -> hence the error. Freeup some of your ram (reduce what you added to intellij etc...)

Comment: Just free your RAM - turn off any program you don't need so you have free 2G for the compiler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56187/discussion-between-vipin8169-and-frant-hartm).

Comment: This solution helps if your unit test fails during 'Make' and not during the actual execution of the test.  Helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As this `OOM` happened during compilation, you need to increase compile VM:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my SpringBootTest configuration has Build (whole project) gradle task in "Before launch". So that's my omission. Eliminating that and issue's gone away.

Or Settings -> Compiler : increase build heap size

Answer (score 0):

To increase heap size is one option.
For me (using subversion for source version control) it was even easier to unload some of the modules which I had checked out and where not directly used for the test. This will also speed up the build process for future tests.

Right click on any module in the project-area of IntelliJ -> Load/Unload modudules -> Choose one/some bigger module and move to the "unload" area.