# Gradle build error: insufficient memory

Tags: android, memory, gradle, out-of-memory

When I build with gradle, it failed with info:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000788800000, 89128960, 0) failed; error='无法分配内存' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 89128960 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/jvm-27885/hs_error.log

:app:transformClassesWithDexForBaiduDebug FAILED
:app:transformClassesWithDexForBaiduDebug (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 25.305 secs.
```

The system memory has 1G left, I think this is enough:

```
Mem:   3921316k total,  2735992k used,  1185324k free,    14464k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    90224k cached
```

Add I added some params into gradle.properties but not worked:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

Is there any other way to fix this memory issue?

[RESOLVED]
After update the physical memory and build passed.

Comment: Increase heap memory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323628/java-outofmemoryerror-insufficient-memory-while-running-junits-in-idea

Comment: Please be careful when creating new tags - the tag `oom` that you created is a duplicate of the tag `out-of-memory`. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will check it carefully later.

Comment: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m - Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I have added gradle.properties with this configuration, but its not working. Its showing the error Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000080000000, 1073741824, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, for me it worked like charm when I increased my Paging File.

Go to : Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings.
Give it 10-20 GB of your hard drive as paging memory if you can.

[image]

[image]