# What is the defaul -Xmx value for Junit run configuration in Intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, run-configuration

I have faced with memory problem and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323628/java-outofmemoryerror-insufficient-memory-while-running-junits-in-idea) which tells to increase `-Xmx` parameter. But when I opened `JUnit` default `Run configuration` I saw no parameter `-Xmx`.

So how to determine the default value for `-Xmx` in `JUnit` in default `Run configuration` for Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link will hep you: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Otherwise Go to Run Configuration, There you will see VM Options, Where you can specify the configurations